# How to open Command Prompt from Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I open the command prompt from a command prompt? `cmd` just gives out data about the command prompt.

My google-fu is failing me - I have already searched but I guess my query is too generic to pinpoint the answer.

Comment: Try this one: `start cmd.exe`

found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303838/create-a-new-cmd-exe-window-from-within-another-cmd-exe-prompt

Comment: `cmd just gives out data about the command prompt` Actually... this is not true. What is does is start **a new** command prompt, just within your current window. You can see that when you do an `exit`. It will return you to your previous prompt (and you'll need to do another `exit` to leave that one). If you want a new **window** with the prompt follow the answer of Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from inside a command prompt window:

```
start cmd.exe
```

Comment: Or even just `start` on its own.